# How to create WKPickerItems on the fly?

Tags: swift2, watchkit, watchos-2

Is there a way to create WKPickerItems within a loop while at the same time adding each item to an array?

I'm doing the following but I'd like to create each WKPickerItem in the append().  Basically moving lines 3 & 4 into the append().

```
1    var items:[WKPickerItem] = [WKPickerItem]()

2    for s in somearray {
3        let item = WKPickerItem()
4        item.title = s
5        items.append(item)
6    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not allow to create UI elements on the fly on watch OS:

> *Updating Your Interface at Runtime*
>
> At runtime, an interface controller can make the following
>   modifications to the objects in its corresponding storyboard scene:
>
> Set or update data values. Change the visual appearance of objects
>   that support such modifications. Change the size of an object. Change
>   the transparency of an object. Show or hide an object. You cannot add
>   new objects to your interface or change the order of the objects that
>   are already there. Although you cannot remove objects, you can hide
>   them, which removes them from the layout temporarily. When an item is
>   hidden, other objects fill in the space previously occupied by the
>   item. To hide an object without filling in the space, set the item’s
>   alpha value to 0. For more information about hiding objects in a
>   scene, see Hiding Interface Objects.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CreatingtheUserInterface.html